# scroll bar to bottom after fetching from mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mysql

I want to move the scroll  bar to bottom after appending/submission of a new text in both side. i.e the scroll bar should be moved to bottom at the user's side who is sending the text and also scroll bar should be moved in the user's side who is receiving the text.

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
           <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">        
           <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
            <div class="row">
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br /> 
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">You Are : <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="chatbox">
                <div id="messages"></div> 
                <div class="area" style="display:none">
                <div class="chat-form">
                <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" id="sub" name="sub">Send</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
<script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var scrolled;
function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if(!scrolled){
        $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
        scrolled=true;
      }

    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#messages").on('scroll',function(){
        scrolled=true;
    });
 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
      scrolled=false;
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();
}, 500);

  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
       $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    });
  });

});
</script>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

the problem is that whenever a new text is added the text goes down to bottom in both the side and the scroll br remain at its position(but should be moved along the new text).

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: Did you checked console?Any errors?

Comment: Also, would you send entire html code?

Comment: @dmitriy yeah. i can send it

Comment: i have edited the code. check it

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: index.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.js:21.
this one

Comment: At the top of all your scripts set $ = jQuery.It seems that you are using old version of jQuery.

Comment: yeah... thats solved my problem but half....
the scroll bar is moved to bottom to the user sending the text,but not to that one who is receiving it.

Comment: Change the order of the jquery and bootstrap scripts. Jquery must be first.

Comment: nope. no change.It doesnt make any difference

Comment: So the query returns the result in the correct order?

Comment: Hmm.... It is returning the results in correct order